# How to determine from which keyboard the input comes

Tags: linux, bash, macos, keyboard, rfid

Scenario:

- I have an usb-RFID reader
- attaching it to notebook it works as an newly attached USB keyboard, e.g. without needing to install any drivers
- when touching the reader with RFID tag
- it enters into my current window (for example terminal/shell) the RFID number (like `0009339384\n`) - e.g. it even sends the `\n`.
- so, it works exactly as if I had **typed** the numbers in my notebook's keyboard

The questions are:

- is it possible read the RFID reader directly without some kernel-level drivers, e.g. something like `cat /dev/keyboard1` ...
- in other words, how can I determine from which "keyboard" the characters are coming?
- using OS X, but would be nice to know the solution for Linux too.

Moreover, I want attach two readers - so I definitely need to clearly differentiate between the two readers. And I want use the rfid-reader in a bash (perl) script, so I'm definitely looking for a solution without compiling some "drivers"... It is possible?

The OS X identifies it as:

```
SYC ID&IC USB Reader:

  Product ID:   0x0035
  Vendor ID:    0xffff
  Version:  1.00
  Serial Number:    08FF20140315
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 18
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

**EDIT** Okay, looks like in Linux it can be done - just found

- this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72483/how-to-distinguish-input-from-different-keyboards
- also [Accessing multiple keyboards input by C++ (or python) in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209252/accessing-multiple-keyboards-input-by-c-or-python-in-linux)

For OS X - exact duplicate on unix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228413/route-keyboard-through-only-dev-ttys000-on-mac-os-x - unfortunately, closed without any answer :(

Comment: hm... also, i'm not sure that i posted this question to the right site - maybe [superuser] would be better...

Comment: I guess that might be the right thing to do @jm666

Comment: Is the USB-RFID  reader is HID device?

Comment: Voted to close with move to superuser but, it is still here... ;(

Comment: @jm666 - If you add some code to the question, then I feel it would be on-topic here (my bar is very low). If you want to have it migrated, then you need to flag it for moderator attention. There is no [author initiated migrations to other SE sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851).

Comment: @LethalProgrammer - hm.. My knowledge about the USB ends at "push this connector inside"... so, it is identified as in my edit...

Comment: By the way, its classical issue with USB HID device, it considers it as the keyboard connected to the machine. For example, if you have the barcode scanner, it considers as the keyboard. In that case, you can just connect the keyboard and hijack the machine.

Comment: Are you trying to get the info via bash only, or are you open to other languages (eg. `C`, `Obj-C`)? It's easily done through Apples Frameworks... (specifically `IOKit.framework`).

Comment: @l'L'l as last resort, mainly because this should be an extremely simple registry system written in bash/perl - e.g: touch the `reader1` at "arrive" touch the `reader2` when leaving. Probably could be done in `swift`, but in such case it wouldn't be easily portable to Linux. But, looks like - it isn't as simple as i thought.

Comment: In that case you could probably query the IOKit registry for any changes directly from bash (`ioreg -l` should reveal a wealth of info, `ioreg -c` for a soecific class). If what you're doing has root privileges another possibly would be `iosnoop`...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so - easily solvable in Linux. As in edits in the question - here are already many similar questions like this.

The solution is: reading the particular `/dev/input/eventN` device(s).

In my case, me using the [Linux::Input](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Input) perl module. Works perfectly.

It is pointless adding code here, the package comes with the [evtest.pl](https://metacpan.org/source/BEPPU/Linux-Input-1.03/bin/evtest.pl) - so anyone could easily check how it works.

Still need solve one issue - e.g. even when reading the device and nicely getting all events from the rfid reader (4 events for one number), the rfid-code still is inserted into the active window, like it coming from a keyboard. (This will be an another question).

For OS X i haven't an easy solution yet, but now focusing for the Linux variant. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is one thing that might help you solve this problem without resorting to programming in C. It is called [multiseat](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat). I didn't do it myself I just know it exists. In general it is a way how multiple people can work on same computer at the same time just using multiple keyboards, mice and monitors. It is not exactly what you are looking for but there might be possible way.

Comment: *"... without resorting to programming in C"* - Stack Overflow is a programming site. This should probably be a comment if remarked at all.

Comment: Wow really? What makes you think that? I didn't notice that he wants solution in C. In fact his tags are linux, bash, osx, keyboard, rfid.  The fact that solution to programming problem in bash can be done completely without programming doesn't make it less solution. Please take your time and go delete your non programming answers on stackoverflow. You have plenty of those.