# Differentiate keyboard events based on USB information

Tags: wxpython

On my system I have 2 keyboards which are able to create `wx.EVT_CHAR` and `wx.EVT_KEY_UP` events. I'm wanting to process the events from keyboard1 differently than the events from keyboard2.

My two keyboards will be physically different types of devices with different `vendorId` and `productId` (USB info).

Is it possible to check the `vendorId` and `productId` which triggered a keyboard event?

Comment: Have a look at `evdev` https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Python has a way to do this directly. wxPython doesn't have any hooks to the OS USB drivers to my knowledge. So I am going to say no, this is not possible with wxPython itself.

But you can go look at the following to see if you can find a workaround:

- [How to determine from which keyboard the input comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542203/how-to-determine-from-which-keyboard-the-input-comes)
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/usbid/1.0.3